# Content Security Policy directive violation with Cloudfront and S3

Tags: html, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, content-security-policy

I am trying to load a webpage which is saved in AWS S3 and uses Cloudfront to load it from my domain. I am receiving the error message below:

```
Refused to load media from 'https://www.example.com/video.mp4' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'media-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I have the following headers in the page which I can see via the browser

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
<html>
<!-- <script src="screen.js"></script> -->
```

It seems that the Content-Security-Policy is being ignored?

I receive the same error in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I managed to get it working, but I am not exactly sure why. I believe that there was a lambda@edge function that was overwriting the header. This can be found under Cloudfront>Distributions>...>Behaviour -> Function associations.
After removing it, I was not able to find the lamda@edge function, so could not verify that it was the problem.

Comment: The reason was in `lambda@edge` function - it was not overwriting your meta tags but add a second CSP via HTTP header. In the case of 2 CSPs, the strictest rules from both policies apply, therefore CSP in meta tag cannot mitigate the CSP published by `lambda@edge`. You should use one of two things: either meta tag or `lambda@edge` function to delivery the policy.

Comment: For those that set up a Cognito S3 environment, I was able to adjust the CSP headers within the configuration.json that comes in the HttpHeadersHandler Lambda script.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to granty for answering this question in the comments above.

The problem was that a lambda@edge was adding a second CSP via HTTP header. In the case of 2 CSPs, the strictest rules from both policies apply, therefore CSP in meta tag cannot mitigate the CSP published by lambda@edge. You should use one of two things: either meta tag or lambda@edge function to delivery the policy